# Will call to static function be overwritten

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-networking, rx-java2

I have 2 classes called **A** and **B**.
Class **B** contains a static function called **calculate** which performs an async network call and stores the data of it locally.

I wanted to know if the following code will kill the async task inside the calculate function.

```
Class A 
{
 B.calculate(); // performs long running async task 
 B.calculate(); // the above call to calculate has not finished but this was called
}
```

Will the async task that started from the first call to calculate continue executing or will it be destroyed and a new task created
?

Answer (score 0):

No, executing an AsyncTask again will not kill the original.  Instead it will add a new task to the async task queue (because by default only 1 async task runs at a time) which will eventually be run causing a 2nd network request.

(Note:  the above assumes you create a new instance of the AsycTask subclass.  If you try to execute the same instance again, you will get an exception.)

Comment: I was planning on switching to using retrofit and rxjava to make the calls,will the same thing happen in that case too?The desired functionality that i require is for the network calls to take place with their respective data no matter how many times calculate is called.

Comment: No clue, depends on how you implement it.  Or you can make it work with AsyncTask if you want to put in a little effort.  You'd have to keep track of if you have a running task and not launch a second one if so.